# How one can capture string that contain one or more forward slash in django urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls

my code look like this

`urls.py:`

```
from django.urls import path
from. import views
app_name ='graduates'
urlpatterns = [
    .
    .
    path('status_detail/<str:id>/', views.status_detail, name='status_detail'),
    
            ]
```

`views.py:`

```
def status_detail(request, id):
      
    return HttpResponse(id)
```

then I wanna use it like this somewhere in my code

```
 <a href=" {% url 'graduates:status_detail' graduate.id %}" class="btn text-secondary "></a>
```

And it works fine for strings those don't contain forward slash.
But I want to pass id of student to urls that look like this
**A/ur4040/09, A/ur5253/09** and etc

Please help me how could I do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use  default Path converters available in django

```
path('status_detail/<path:id>/', views.status_detail, name='status_detail'),
```

**path** - Matches any non-empty string, including the path separator, '/'.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your url into a regex:

```
url(r'^status_detail/(?P<str:id>\w+)/', views.status_detail, name='status_detail')
```

If `url` doesn't work because you have urls with same structure, use `re_path`:

```
re_path(r'^status_detail/(?P<str:id>\w+)/', views.status_detail, name='status_detail')
```

Don't forget to import `re_path`:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: thanks for showing possible way. But it isn't working yet shows error `raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: "^detail/(?P<str:id>\w+)/" is not a valid regular expression: bad character in group name 'str:id' at position 12`

Comment: My bad, the structure of a regex on urls is: **(?P<name>pattern)** so in this case might work: `url(r'^status_detail/(?P<id>\w+)/', views.status_detail, name='status_detail')`